# How to maintain in an enum a list of enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enum Flags Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

I've seen in Windows Forms that when you use a control which contains Anchor, you can set several enums at the same time.

I was trying to do that, but I haven't accomplished yet:

```
enum Foo
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

Foo foo = A | B;   // here just receive the last one
```

Is possible doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Flags attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).

Flags:

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0x0,
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the Flags attribute.

```
[Flags]
enum Foo 
{ 
  A = 1, 
  B = 2, 
  C = 4 
}


var foo = Foo.A | Foo.B;
```

More information here: [What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)